Select specific pixels of an image
I'm using C and stb_image, and image data is stored in an unsigned char* where a group of 4 elements represents a pixel, with r, g, b, and a channels respectively. I'm trying to get pixels of part of an image, for a sort of spritesheet loader. Currently I have this:
static void getGlyphTexture(unsigned char *dataOut, unsigned char *dataIn, size_t bitmapWidth, size_t glyphSize, size_t index) {
    for (size_t y = 0; y < glyphSize; y++) {
        for (size_t x = 0; x < glyphSize; x++) {
            dataOut[4 * (glyphSize * x + y) + 0] = dataIn[4 * (bitmapWidth * x + y) + 0];
            dataOut[4 * (glyphSize * x + y) + 1] = dataIn[4 * (bitmapWidth * x + y) + 1];
            dataOut[4 * (glyphSize * x + y) + 2] = dataIn[4 * (bitmapWidth * x + y) + 2];
            dataOut[4 * (glyphSize * x + y) + 3] = dataIn[4 * (bitmapWidth * x + y) + 3];
        }
    }
}

The above code takes in an image dataIn and outputs part of the image into dataOut. It works fine right now, copying the very first segment of the image, of glyphSize * glyphSize dimensions.

However, I cannot figure out the math to get the pixels offset from that starting point, say to get this part of the spritesheet.

I either get a buffer overflow error, or the data is not correct at all. Does anyone have any idea on the correct math to manipulate the array to select all the latter parts of the image?

4 * ( bitmapWidth * y + glyphSize * g + x ) + c.

@ikegami apologies, I still don't follow what s is supposed to be.

You're asking to select the sprite, so s is the sprite offset. I've already renamed it to g since your existing vars call them glyphs.

@ikegami alright it's close (4 * ( bitmapWidth * y + glyphSize * index + x ) + n )but the way that the data is being copied flips the image based on the index. Is there any way to counteract this?

You didn't specify the order of the pixels in the array, so I assumed standard English reading order (left-to-right, top-to-bottom). If that's not correct, you'll need to provide more info.

Generally, when accessing bitmap pixels the formula is  (image_width * y )+ x.    But you're saying (image_width * x) + y (in your own words).   Unless you're doing something very unusual that I don't understand, I don't think that code will serve you.

The solution that I came to is this, assuming that the bitmap only stretches on the x axis (for my purposes).
static void getGlyphTexture(unsigned char *dataOut, unsigned char *dataIn, size_t bitmapWidth, size_t glyphSize, size_t index) {
    for (size_t y = 0; y < glyphSize; y++) {
        for (size_t x = 0; x < glyphSize; x++) {
            dataOut[4 * ((glyphSize * y) + x) + 0] = dataIn[4 * ( bitmapWidth * y + glyphSize * index + x ) + 0];
            dataOut[4 * ((glyphSize * y) + x) + 1] = dataIn[4 * ( bitmapWidth * y + glyphSize * index + x ) + 1];
            dataOut[4 * ((glyphSize * y) + x) + 2] = dataIn[4 * ( bitmapWidth * y + glyphSize * index + x ) + 2];
            dataOut[4 * ((glyphSize * y) + x) + 3] = dataIn[4 * ( bitmapWidth * y + glyphSize * index + x ) + 3];
        }
    }
}

